# How to search a buffer for a numeric range which contains a given value

Tags: emacs, text-search

I have a buffer which holds some lldb output which contains a lot of address ranges like `[0x00007fff60489000-0x00007fff604c0000)`.

Given an address (in hex as well), how would I search for a range which contains that address? I assume this will need some custom elisp code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `calc` for this. The syntax for hexadecimals is slightly different, and I won't show how to convert them, but the core of your functionality can be written as follows.

```
(require 'calc)

(defun is-between (n low high)
  (and (equal "1" (calc-eval (concat n " - " low " > 0")))
       (equal "1" (calc-eval (concat high " - " n " > 0")))))

(is-between "16#f0" "16#f" "16#ff")
```

Comment: This provides only a predicate for testing a number, not an answer for how to search for its occurrence. Consider beefing up your answer by providing a search command. Hint: bind variable `isearch-filter-predicate`.